# font size okular note (pop-up)

Tags: fonts, okular

I am using Okular on Ubuntu 20.04 and the font for pop-up notes was okay until one day it shrinks so now I have to manually go into properties and resize on each note.

How can I configure a default size?

[image: difference]

Right hand size was the old default and left is after I adjusted in properties to two different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Select Configure Okular from Settings.  Select Annotations on the left.  Double click on the Insert Text tool.  Default font and text color can be changed.